# Access Joomla Database

Tags: mysql, database, joomla

I'm trying to move a joomla site from one person's hosting account to another. Thus I'm really limited in which tools I have.

The problem I'm having to trying to get access to the mysql database. I don't have access to ssh, cpanel, phpmyadmin, or anything else of the nature, just joomla admin and ftp access.

However joomla gives me some database settings.
But when I try to connect to the given hostname, nothing happens.
I'm trying something like and it just hangs

```
mysql -u myusername -h thegivendomain.db.3456321.hostedresource.com jos_giventable name
```

I even tried digging the hostname and tried using the ip for the hostname.

and ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [the free Akeeba Backup](http://akeebabackup.com/) it will make a complete copy of the website that you can download. Upload that to the new server and install with [their Kickstart script](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html).

Run Kickstart from any browser on the new host and follow the steps.

Comment: yes you need an extension or pluguin to do it (database backup)

Answer (score 2):

It is reasonable to assume that their firewall just blocks remote access to the MySQL service, so your attempts to connect don't reach their destination.

Seeing how you are familiar with shell in general, you could try a PHP shell wrapper, such as [this one I made for myself](https://github.com/DCoderLT/Misc_Tools/blob/master/sh/sh.php) - if the hosting company is not too uptight about their security, this script will be able to run shell commands, e.g. `mysqldump -uusername -ppassword db > backup.sql`.

Comment: This is a hardcore solution that I'm glad I didn't have to get to. The plugins worked nice to both backup and restore the database. Thank you.